# I am having problrems with ffmpeg

Tags: windows

I am learning to build webites and progressing well. however I am slightly confused about FFMPEG.

Is this a tool/ program that has to be on my computer to use?

Or

Can I add the file to root of my website for the use of my site users?

Mark

Comment: FFMPEG is used to create .mp4 and other formats of video and audio. It does not need to be on your system with Windows. Usually people like to use it with streaming, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Is FFmpeg a tool/ program that has to be on my computer to use?

FFmpeg must be installed on whatever computer (or server) you plan to use it on directly (i.e. the executable).

> Can I add the file to root of my website for the use of my site users?

If you want users to be able to use FFmpeg on your server, you must give them a way to connect to it. This may mean already having FFmpeg running so they can connect to it directly or sometimes this may mean having another set of software or scripts that runs or connects to FFmpeg on their behalf. Simply placing FFmpeg in the root of your web site won't typically allow users to use FFmpeg.

Comment: Thank you for your help *** Anaksunaman  ***your answer is helpful and given me a better understanding I was watching youtube and getting so confused, due the the fact I was unaware how flexible ffmpeg could be.

Comment: You're welcome. FFmpeg can definitely  be confusing. =)